# checked checkbox remain after re-rendering

Tags: reactjs

i'm building a checkbox todo List that checked checkbox is disappearing.

I have two problems.

1. checked checkbox remains after re-rendering
2. When the two checkboxes are left, they dont disappear.

Here is my codeSandBox:-----

I think this might be a `setState` issue,  `setItems([...items.filter((item) => !checkedItems[item.id])]);` ->  rerendering (this scope have`checkedItems ={false,true,false,false,false}`) so, checkbox is remaining?

```
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";

const todos = [
  { id: 0, value: "Wash the dishes" },
  { id: 1, value: "have lunch" },
  { id: 2, value: "listen to music" },
  { id: 3, value: "running" },
  { id: 4, value: "work out" }
];
export default function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState(todos);
  const [checkedItems, setCheckedItems] = React.useState(
    new Array(todos.length).fill(false)
  );

  const checkHandler = (idx) => {
    checkedItems[idx] = !checkedItems[idx];
    setItems([...items.filter((item) => !checkedItems[item.id])]);
    setCheckedItems([...checkedItems]);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {items.map((todo, idx) => (
        <div key={idx}>
          <span>{todo.value}</span>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={checkedItems[idx]}
            onChange={() => checkHandler(idx)}
          ></input>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that item.id won't match the index once an item is removed from the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not good practice to use index as key when iterating objects.
Since you have `id`, use this.

```
  {items.map(todo => (
    <div key={todo.id}>
      <span>{todo.value}</span>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={checkedItems[todo.id]}
        onChange={() => checkHandler(todo.id)}
      ></input>
    </div>
  ))}
```

You mess with indexes and the result is confusing.
If you want the items to be persisted and shown, just remove this line

```
setItems([...items.filter((item) => !checkedItems[item.id])]);
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/old-voice-6xyovb?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to have a separate `checkedItems` state. You can add a field `checked` in your `todo` object.

```js
const todos = [
  { id: 0, value: "Wash the dishes", checked: false },
  { id: 1, value: "have lunch", checked: false },
  { id: 2, value: "listen to music", checked: false },
  { id: 3, value: "running", checked: false },
  { id: 4, value: "work out", checked: false }
];
export default function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState(todos);


  const checkHandler = (idx) => {
    setItems(items.filter((item) => item.id !== idx));
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {items.map((todo, idx) => (
        <div key={idx}>
          <span>{todo.value}</span>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={todo.checked}
            onChange={() => checkHandler(todo.id)}
          ></input>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The key mistake you're making here is in `onChange={() => checkHandler(idx)}` and then using `idx` as your variable to filter out your items. `idx` does NOT equal the `ids` you have in your todo list, it will change based on the number of items left in the array.

The filter can also be improved to just be

`setItems([...items.filter((item) => item.id !== idx)]);`

The final code should look something like this (I'm not sure what checkedItems is meant to be doing or what it's for so it's not a consideration in this answer).

```
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";

const todos = [
  { id: 0, value: "Wash the dishes" },
  { id: 1, value: "have lunch" },
  { id: 2, value: "listen to music" },
  { id: 3, value: "running" },
  { id: 4, value: "work out" }
];
export default function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState(todos);
  const [checkedItems, setCheckedItems] = React.useState(
    new Array(todos.length).fill(false)
  );

  const checkHandler = (idx) => {
    checkedItems[idx] = !checkedItems[idx];
    setItems([...items.filter((item) => item.id !== idx)]);
    setCheckedItems([...checkedItems]);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {items.map((todo, idx) => (
        <div key={idx}>
          <span>{todo.value}</span>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            onChange={() => checkHandler(todo.id)}
          ></input>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove this line:

```
setItems([...items.filter((item) => !checkedItems[item.id])]);
```

that causes the list items to be filtered.